# Primefaces dataTable: Is it possible to conditionally show a button?

Tags: primefaces, jsf-2.2

I have a dataTable and there is a button in the last column. Depending on the data in the first column, I need the button to be either a simple button or a splitButton (offering more actions).

**Is there a way to achieve this ?**

My dataTable:

```
<p:column headerText="id">
    <h:outputText value="#{myvar.id}" />
</p:column>

<p:column>    
    <p:splitButton value="View"
        actionListener="#{bean.method}" />    
    <p:menuitem value="Other action"
        actionListener="#{bean.method2" />    
    </p:splitButton>    
</p:column>
```

I don't always need the "Other action". I depends on the data in the current row, for example myvar.id. Any suggestions ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can create your own condition and apply it in the `Rendred` for example create a `Boolean` in your `ManagedBean` and change it value with the data type and make it like that `Rendred ="#{managedBeand.condition}"`

Comment: When i read your post i understand something different when you talk about showing or not a button you can work with `Rendred` or `Disabled`

Comment: Thanks, I already checked the showcase and I am already using var, but I am not sure how to affect the structure of the table ?

Comment: i will provide an example it will be more clear `<p:column headerText="Action" width="100"><p:commandButton  icon="ui-icon-close"  title="Delete" actionListener="#{ManagedBean.remove(YourVar)}"  >
                    </p:commandButton>`

Comment: I updated my question with an additional column

Comment: Hope that you see my example

Comment: I think you misunderstood my question. I want the button to be different depending on the data in the table. Look at my code. For example: If myvar.id is even, I would like a single button, but if myvar.id is uneven, I would like the button to have another option.

Comment: ooooo i understand it is simple your have to use Rendred  and add a condition look at this example `<p:column>    
    <p:splitButton value="View"
        actionListener="#{bean.method}"  rendered="false" />    
    <p:menuitem value="Other action" rendered="true" 
        actionListener="#{bean.method2" />    
    </p:splitButton>    
</p:column>`

Comment: You can create your own condition and apply it in the `Rendred` for example create a `Boolean` in your `ManagedBean` and change it value with the data type and make it like that `Rendred ="#{managedBeand.condition}"`

Comment: Your last comment solved my problem. Please update your answer and I'll accept it :)